# JSON structure in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, rest-api, json, callout

How would i store this kind of JSON structure in salesforce?

```
"elementOne": [
  {
    "itemOne":"valueOne",
    "itemTwo":"valueTw0",
    "embeddedElementOne":{"embeddedItemOne":"embeddedValueOne"},
    "embeddedElementTwo":{"embeddedItemTwo":"embeddedValueTwo"}
   }
],
 "elementTwo":[
   {
     "secondElementOne":"Value",
     "secondEmbeddedElementOne":{"SomethingHere":"SomeValueHere"}
   }
]
```

If elementOne is **Custom Object** and itemOne, itemTwo are **fields** on that Object, what would embeddedElementOne will be? How and where to store that and how would send the same kind of structure when using POST method?

Answer (score 0):

Your two objects, elementOne and elementTwo, would be related using lookup fields. For elementOne, it would be a lookup to elementOne (this is legal), and for elementTwo, it would have a lookup to elementOne as well. Depending on which API you decide to use (likely the [sobject tree API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm) or the [nested records API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_create.htm)), you would format your JSON according to the documentation, and the records would be inserted/updated appropriately.